# After upgrading to 20.04, my PHP+MySQL website stopped working

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I had Ubuntu 16.04 where I could run a local website with PHP and MySQL.

I upgraded to 20.04 and installed PHP 5.6 and linked it to Apache2:

```
sudo apt install php5.6
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php5.6
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

I can still open the website in localhost and run PHP pages, but MySQL does not work. I do have mysql on my system (when I run "mysql" I see the "MariaDB" prompt), but it is probably not connected to PHP or to Apache. When I run phpinfo from the browser, I see the following under "Additional .ini files parsed":

> /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini

Answer (score 0):

PHP is installed and MySQL is installed, but there is a missing link - the module that connects the two.  It can be installed by:

```
sudo apt install php5.6-mysql
```

(5.6 should be replaced by the version pf php you have installed).

Then, do not forget to restart the apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now, the list of ini files in phpinfo is updated and contains mysql:

> /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, **/etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,** /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini